# XAMPP - Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4 - Windows 10

Tags: apache, windows-services, xampp, pid, windows-10

Upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and got an 
Apache error (in XAMPP v3.2.1)

```
Problem detected!
Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

as all the forums state:

1. **Skype**: skype uses port 80/443 by default. You can change this from
   tools->options-> advanced->connections and disable checkbox "use
   port 80 and 443 for addtional incoming connections".
2. **IIS**: IIS uses port 80 be default so you need to shut down it. You can use the following two commands net stop w3svc net stop
   iisadmin
3. **SQL Server Reporting Service**: You need to stop this service because it may take port 80 if IIS is not running. Go to local
   services and stop it.

Once I had disabled Skype I had to find the Windows10 Service causing my issue.
It was the **World Wide Web Publishing Service** (in the Internet Information Service) Service Host
[image]

Hope this can help someone

Comment: I ran into that same problem just last week. I know this will help many people.